# Drawing the letter 'R' in python Turtle

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I have slight problems creating the 'R' letter in turtle. Here is my code for it

```
import turtle

t = turtle.Turtle()
t.forward(100)
t.right(90)
t.forward(75)
t.right(90)
t.forward(50)
t.left(120)
t.forward(75)
t.left(-120)
t.forward(25)
t.right(60)
t.forward(75)
t.left(150)
t.forward(70)
t.left(-90)
t.forward(25)
t.right(90)
t.forward(145)
```

Could someone help me improve how to write the 'R' letter, currently it is not that accurate?

Comment: What isn't accurate about it, specifically, and what attempt have you made to rectify that problem?

Comment: "currently it is not that accurate?" - **what does this mean**? How do you think it should be different? What is your understanding of the existing code, and about why you get the result you do? Are you confused about what the code is already doing? It's your responsibility to figure out the requirements for the code; we only answer questions about the implementation. For example, if you want to be able to draw a circular arc, ask about that. If you want to add more sides somewhere or change their lengths or angles, then do that. Figuring out what lengths or angles you want is off topic.

Answer (score -1):

One way to do it is like this:

```
import turtle
t = turtle.Turtle()
t.circle(50, 180)
t.left(90)
t.forward(200)
t.right(180)
t.forward(100)
t.right(150)
t.forward(115)
```

Comment: Please add explanation to your code as it is hard to understand.

Answer (score -1):

Here are two solutions - a boxy solution like your original attempt, and a rounded R. You need to use turtle.penup() so you can move the turtle to the center of the R and turtle.pendown() to start drawing again.

In both cases, I shifted the right leg of the R slightly to the right so that is is more even with the right edge of the top, and I also made it slightly taller so that it is about even with the left leg.  Some small tweaks may still be needed.

Here is the boxy version:
[image: Rectangular letter 'R']

```
import turtle
t = turtle.Turtle()
t.forward(100)
t.right(90)
t.forward(75)
t.right(90)

# Start bottom and draw leg
t.forward(40)
t.left(120)
t.forward(83)
t.left(-120)
t.forward(25)
t.right(60)
t.forward(83)
t.left(60)
t.forward(10)
t.left(90)
# end right leg, start left leg
t.forward(70)
t.left(-90)
t.forward(25)
t.right(90)
t.forward(145)
# outside done.

# Move to center cut out
t.penup()
t.right(90)
t.forward(25)
t.right(90)
t.forward(25)
t.pendown()
t.forward(25)
t.left(90)
t.forward(50)
t.left(90)
t.forward(25)
t.left(90)
t.forward(50)
t.exitonclick()
```

And here is the rounded version:
[image: Rounded letter 'R']

```
t = turtle.Turtle()
t.forward(63)
t.circle(-37.5, 180)

# Start bottom and draw leg
t.forward(2.5)
t.left(120)
t.forward(83)
t.left(-120)
t.forward(25)
t.right(60)
t.forward(83)
t.left(60)
t.forward(10)
t.left(90)
# end right leg, start left leg
t.forward(70)
t.left(-90)
t.forward(25)
t.right(90)
t.forward(145)
# outside done.

# Move to center cut out
t.penup()
t.right(90)
t.forward(25)
t.right(90)
t.forward(25)
t.pendown()
t.forward(25)
t.left(90)
t.forward(37.5)
t.circle(12.5, 180)
t.forward(37.5)
t.exitonclick()
```

Answer (score -2):

```
import turtle

t = turtle.Turtle()

# Draw the vertical line of 'R'
t.forward(100)
t.right(90)
t.forward(75)
t.right(90)
t.forward(100)

# Draw the slanted leg of 'R'
t.left(180)
t.forward(50)
t.left(120)
t.forward(75)
t.left(60)
t.forward(35)

turtle.done()
```

Changes made:

Used `turtle.done()` at the end to keep the window open after drawing.
Corrected the angles to ensure the 'R' is drawn accurately.
Adjusted the lengths and angles to create a more balanced 'R' shape.
Feel free to experiment with the values to adjust the size and proportions of the letter 'R' according to your preference.

Comment: This doesn't even look like an 'R', particularly compared to what the OP's code produces.  Perhaps you could include the output image from your code in your post to better understand what you're seeing vs. what Python does with it on my computer.